# How to connect the "tabletop" and "feet" of a small, wooden, take-apart desk riser?

Tags: furniture, wooden-furniture, self-assembly-furniture

I want to build a small desk riser (W 30.4 cm × D 21.5 cm × H 20 cm) for my laptop. It should be lightweight, not resonate (so no cardboard box), sufficiently stable, and I need to be able to take it apart or fold it without tools for travelling.

If I didn't need to take it apart, I would build a simple small table like this, that has remained from when my son was smaller and that I now use to create a standing desk from a table of normal height:

[image: image of a small children's desk on top of a normal desk]

or a simple desk riser screwed together from a plain board and two square timbers to put my monitor at eye height (I'm tall):

[image: image of a simple wooden desk riser]

My son recommended simple dowel joints:

[image: image of dowel joints]

But I'm worried they will wear out quickly and the desk riser will become instable.

I have also thought of using metal connectors like this one:

[image: image of the Knapp Uno 30 connector]

I hesitate, because I have no experience with them. I don't know how they work for my purpose, as they are commonly used to connect furniture parts and not for something that is assembled and disassembled daily. I would also have to buy the appropriate tools first and don't really want to make that investment.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you need to store the pieces in several different locations? or have you just not considered folding furniture?

Comment: For the amount of movement, I would suggest folding legs.  Most of those hinges have a lock, and are quite common.

Comment: @Jasen I have considered folding legs but was worried they would be rickety and both not stand stable as well as make a noise. I want to use the desk riser in a library and need it to be silent once assembled. It shouldn't rattle.

Comment: @crip659 See my preceding comment. But is there a hinge with locks that you are familiar with and would recommend? I had some difficulty searching and mostly found larger hinges for fold-away shelves. I find that finding these things is quite difficult if you don't know their proper names...

Comment: Holy carp that Knapp Uno connector thing is a pricey bit of kit! They're _quite_ proud of those...

Comment: A quick search for folding hinges for table legs shows quite a few.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The table in your first photo is a perfect example of what you *should* do. The legs on such tables often mount with a single diagonal bolt or screw (which could be a wing nut or knobbed bolt), creating a very stable triangulated structure:

[image]

This technique requires no special tools and is tolerant of brace placement error. The key is mostly that you mount the side rails well to the top, which provides additional stability.

See also: [Attaching Legs to a Table](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/2821/attaching-legs-to-a-table) at the Woodworking Stack.

---

If you want something simpler to build, [threaded attachment plates](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Waddell-Heavy-Duty-Top-Plate-5-5-in-x-3-in-16G-Steel-Mounting-Hardware-Furniture-Leg-Easy-Installation-2755/100390125) should be more than stable enough for such a short table.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I want a table that I can take apart and assemble without tools. Could you explain how your solution solves that requirement? I may not understand it completely.

Comment: Use whatever fastener you like where the drill resides in that photo. Put a knob on it if you want.

Comment: or buy an allen key and make a little hole to stow it in under the table.

Comment: Ah, I get it! (Your first photo and recommendation.) Thank you. I didn't think to use a manually removable faster. But I like your second solution even better. I've actually handled something like this and it was tight and fast. I think I'll go with that. Thanks!